# Syntax error when trying to use a column named `lineno`

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've MYSQL and MSSQL query. MYSQL Query is working fine but same Query modified as a MSSQL Query is showing error.

In this MSSQL Query testCaseName is VARBINARY(MAX) type.

MYSQL QUERY:

```
update tce_lineno 
set testcasename=concat(concat(testcasename,','),:tcname) 
where lineno=:lineno and project=:project
```

MSSQL QUERY:

```
update tce_lineno 
set testcasename=((testcasename +',')+'rosdsadp') 
where lineno='23' and project='proj001';
```

ERROR IS:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'lineno'

How can I modified in correct way?

Comment: Don't use `varbinary(max)`, that's a blob type.

Comment: The message is unrelated to the title, it doesn't even mention the text column or the `CONCAT` function

Comment: Yes,In MYSQL using blob type for testCaseName,thatsy I used varbinary(max) type in MSSQL.

Comment: Moreover, the T-SQL statement uses a hard-coded value instead of a parameter (eg `@lineno`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lineno` is a [reserved word in TSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) and needs to be escapes with brackets

```
where [lineno] = '23' and project = 'proj001';
```

Comment: Is any other way to avoid this error,The data types varbinary(max) and varchar are incompatible in the add operator. When trying to update record.